# How does Linux know if a new password is a "wrapped" version of a old one?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-policy

**How does Linux know if a new password is a "wrapped" version of an old password?
(or, the process of creating a new password) know "certain" parts of one's password?**

Let's say I have the password `abcEFGH123321` and I set a new password to be: `acbdEFGH123321` (added a `d`).
it displays:

`new password is a wrapped version of the/an old password`

#### My guess

..is that the whatever application handling the **setting & reading new & old account / sudo passwords**    maybe hashes **X** amount of the first bits of the entered password,

#### For example;

Say the password `abcd` is set,
via `passwd` (e.g) and, you change it (the password)

`abcd` to `abdc` (swapping the last 2 characters).

Does it maybe take the old password: `abcd` and hash the first 3 characters of it?

```
H₁ -> H('a') -> stores it
H₂ -> H('b') -> stores it

and so on, for - x times. (in this case, maybe x is a hard-coded constant , 3 for example)
```

#### If it stores this:

Where does it?

Where does it store the "parts"? Note I am not asking in general - *if* it knows this - But rather *how it does it*.
An explanation answer- with references would be great!

Comment: Or maybe it just tries wrapped versions of the newly entered password and checks if a hashed version of it just matches the existing password? Because "new is wrapped old password" is the same as "old is wrapped new one". Nothing to save for this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That could really be a way too.. I did not think about that at all, actually

Comment: I suppose it could detect `abcEFGH123321 --> abcdEFGH123321` through trial hashing (ie try something and hash it to see if that matches the stored hash), by deleting each single letter and trying it. But if it's doing that, would it also need to try CAPS'ing each letter? l33t subs? Adding / removing random punctuation at the end? That would quickly add up to a lot of computation...

Comment: Yeah, and think about the security of it as well; (I think of - if it even does this; (this as we discuss it as) Isn't this a very bad idea? (because, the risk - of partial password-hashes leaking out is increasing) (the partial hash of the same password, which - is introducing some "beginning" for adversaries to start cribbing attacks, or *some* other way of attacking this)

Comment: What versions of the software are running on your system? The [cracklib](https://github.com/cracklib/cracklib) library that most distributions use will compare the old and new passwords when you supply them (when just using passwd and supplying the old password). I don't see any libraries that will actually work on the new password to try and find previous hashes.

Comment: It was a long time ago, I do not know at all at this point, but how it would be possible (since, it did display the message, I do not if Linux systems do this now - really this is all why I ask this question) but, thanks for providing the cracklib - I will at least take a look into it :)

Comment: I think it's simply taking each substring of the newly-entered password, and hashing each one to see any match the hash of the current password.  If a password is 12 characters long, there are 364 possible substrings - the user would probably not even notice a delay on most systems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is [cracklib](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246217/how-does-linux-know-if-a-new-password-is-a-wrapped-version-of-a-old-one#comment507118_246217).

CrackLib will take the new password and modify it in a lot of ways to see if the modification is the same as the current password, that you had to type before changing the password.

So if your old password is
`acbEFGH123321` and the new is `acbdEFGH123321`, and Linux complains, it means cracklib took the new password, added/dropped chars on each position, and discovered that you added one single letter. And that's bad.

Performance penalty on this is negligible. Linux have both the old and the new passwords, and a simple compare between strings can detect differences.

Comment: +1.  WRT *'Linux have both the old and the new passwords, and a simple compare between strings can detect differences'* - you mean that linux has the salted hash of the old password, correct?  So, it's a little more than just a string comparison, as each modification of the new password must be salted and hashed in order to compare it with the salted hash of the old password.  But, still negligible for a reasonable number of modifications.

Comment: No, you have to provide the old password *before* entering the new one, so Linux has both passwords in clear.

Comment: Ah, good point.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Yes oh my; I did not think of that at all, really - this is now when I think about it, really obvious. (Deceptively simple) Of course you type the old password and *then* the new one,  thanks so much for pointing that out. **totally forgot that.**, Genius!

Comment: As a remark, it is the reason why this limits do not apply when the change is done by the super user, because the new password is entered but the old one is not.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Oh, I - was a bout to say that you were wrong but;  read the last parts of your comment, which - really, it's true. Thanks for pointing that out too, I didn't consider that either,  good thing I asked here! Thanks again.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I don't think that's really true.  Even without knowing the old password, the `passwd` command could still (try to) prevent root from setting a 2 character password.  But it doesn't.  I think the real reason is for that behavior when running as root is:  so one can do whatever one wants to do with a computer that one is root on, without needing to fight too much with a utility program which (was written by a company which) knows better than you.

Comment: You *could* check without having the old password in plain text. Just modify the new password in various ways, then hash it as if it was a login attempt against the old hash. If it matches, you've found a similar modification between the old and new password. However, this is very performance-intensive because you have to run the password hashing algorithm (which is expensive) for each candidate modification.

Comment: If, as you say in the comments, this is only ever done with access to the old and new passwords in the clear, you only really need to calculate the [Levenshtein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the two. Cracklib does far more tests so is far more comprehensive

Comment: @mti2935 so you mean it does this PLAINTEXT? :O

Comment: @ChrisH that is awezome; thanks for the external readings!